# Including a Text File As a Local Resource in an exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have a text file that I would like to include in a stand alone executable. The file itself sits in source control in another directory and I think I want to have the text file added to the executable at compile time.

I've been reading a bit about resources but I'm not sure exactly what would be the best way to add the file. I also don't know how I would reference and read from the file during execution.

The project is statically linked MFC, and I'm using vs2010. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the file as a resource into your application. You can "read" it with code similar to this:

```
/* the ID is whatever ID you choose to give the resource. The "type" is
 * also something you choose. It will most likely be something like "TEXTFILE"
 * or somesuch. But anything works.
 */
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(NULL, <ID of your resource>, _T("<type>")); 
HGLOBAL hGlobal = NULL;
DWORD dwTextSize = 0;

if(hRes != NULL)
{
    /* Load the resource */
    hGlobal = LoadResource(NULL, hRes);

    /* Get the size of the resource in bytes (i.e. the size of the text file) */
    dwTextSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hRes);
}

if(hGlobal != NULL)
{ 
    /* I use const char* since I assume that your text file is saved as ASCII. If
     * it is saved as UNICODE adjust to use const WCHAR* instead but remember 
     * that dwTextSize is the size of the memory buffer _in bytes_).
     */
    const char *lpszText = (const char *)LockResource(hGlobal);

    /* at this point, lpszText points to a block of memory from which you can
     * read dwTextSize bytes of data. You *CANNOT* modify this memory.
     */
    ... whatever ...
}
```